# Geoserver SLD: How to get CENTROID of result of INTERSECTION?

Tags: geoserver, sld, centroids, chart

In my GeoServer SLD I need to place a symbol (particularly a piechart) exactly on Centroid of the result of Intersection of 2 geometry:

- geom field from my PostGIS table AND
- environment variable WMS_BBOX

My aim is to place my Piechart on centroid of shown part of a polygon (an not on centroid of the whole polygon itself).

Ian Turton commented on my [previous](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/227189/18383) question with the following Geometry element in SLD, and to use it in `<PointSymbolizer>`:

```
<Geometry>
  <ogc:Function name="intersection">
    <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
    <ogc:Function name="env">
      <ogc:Literal>wms_bbox</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:Function>
   </ogc:Function>
</Geometry>
```

The problem is, with the above Geometry (of intersection between geom field and WMS_BBOX) the piechart is shown in every geometry element of my multipolygon table. And this is surely not desirable.

[image: -gambar piechart per polygon-]

This effect is similar to forcing a `<PointSymbolizer>` Rule (below) to a multipolygon table.

```
<Rule>
<PointSymbolizer>
    <Graphic>
        <Mark>
            <WellKnownName>square</WellKnownName>
            <Fill><CssParameter name="fill">#FF0000</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
        </Mark>
        <Size>6</Size>
    </Graphic>
</PointSymbolizer>
</Rule>
```

The above style enforcement gives the below layer (these islands belong to 1 row of a multipolygon table).

[image]

Again this is not desirable.

So then i tried the `<ogc:Function name="centroid">`. Thinking that this is equivalent to a PostGIS command of

```
ST_CENTROID(
    ST_INTERSECTION(
        geometry_field, --of my multipolygon table
        WMS_BBOX
        ))
```

... then I wrote the following in my SLD:

```
<Geometry>
    <ogc:Function name="centroid">
        <ogc:Function name="intersection">
            <ogc:PropertyName>geom</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Function name="env">
                <ogc:Literal>wms_bbox</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:Function>
        </ogc:Function>
    </ogc:Function>
</Geometry>
```

However my WMS preview throws this error:

```
code:"internalError:Rendering process failed
Filter Function problem for function centroid argument #0 - expected type Geometry
```

This is as if `Centroid` argument expects a geometry type but `Intersection` argument gives non-geometry type. The GeoServer [Geometric functions reference](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function_reference.html) however, while clearly states the type of arguments input, does not states clearly the type of the output.

Question:

- why does `centroid` argument fail on my `intersection`?
- how to solve it?

My playground:

- GeoServer 2.14.3 (with chart extension)
- Apache Tomcat 8.5.32 Server
- Windows 10 Pro 64-bit on Xeon E5-1660 3GHz, 32GB memory
- PostgreSQL 9.6.11, PostGIS 2.5

Comment: Wait, after another extra patience I zoom/pan the GeoServer layer preview that initially throws _"Filter Function problem for function centroid argument #0 - expected type Geometry"_. It appears that in some certain area of the map, GeoServer throws the error message, while not in some other. I am pretty sure that the area with error message, there's invalid geometry. I think when geometry is invalid, `Intersection` throws error message, and in turn `Centroid` argument will throw error that it gets unexpected data type (that is the error message as oppose to a geometry).

Comment: please use the [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/326669/edit) link to update your question rather than using comments to add information

Comment: I think your geometry is called "the_geom" not "geom" hence the error message